# Adding MassTransit Consumer to a Asp.net Framework Web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq, masstransit, .net-4.8

I am Tring to add MassTransit Consumer to a Asp.net Framework (.net 4.8) Web application. I not see any sample that use .net framework , all sample point to .NET Core .

**Is this Supported by MassTransit in .net Framework (.net 4.8). Is this Long running calls will be killed Off by IIS ?**

My sample Code for Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    static IBusControl _bus;
    static BusHandle _busHandle;

    public static IBus Bus
    {
        get { return _bus; }
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        _bus = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQHost"]), h =>
            {
                h.Username("admin");
                h.Password("admin");
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(RA_Listener.RA_Listener0, e =>
            {
                e.Consumer<EventConsumer>();
            });
        });

        _busHandle = MassTransit.Util.TaskUtil.Await<BusHandle>(() => _bus.StartAsync());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only a long-running call if the bus can't connect to your message broker. Otherwise, it should complete almost immediately. So if your broker is unreachable, that's likely the issue.

> Also, you should be configuring an `ILoggerFactory` and providing it to MassTransit if you expect to see any useful log output to help you troubleshoot any issues. Configure logging using `LogContext.ConfigureCurrentLogContext(loggerFactory);` within the bus configuration closure.

You could just create the bus, as you've done, and use:

`Task.Run(() => _bus.StartAsync());`

It won't wait, but you also won't know if the bus actually started since you aren't observing the result of the task. But, at least it won't block your startup.